# Browserify with jQuery >= 2 produces "jQuery requires a window with a document"

Tags: javascript, jquery, commonjs, browserify

I'm using browserify to bundle my front-end javascript using CommonJS-style dependencies. For example, I have:

```
$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery');  // v2.1.0-beta2                                                                                                                                                                       
_ = require('underscore');                                                                                                                                                                                 
Backbone = require('backbone');
```

However, when browserify bundles the dependencies I run into the following console error:

```
Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
```

Looking at the jQuery code, I see it's trying to use `this` for the global `window`.

```
(function( window, factory ) {
....
}(this, function( window ) {
```

Since browserify wraps all dependencies, `this` is an `object`, not the `window`.

What's interesting is jQuery >= 2 should be CommonJS compatible. However, the problem is how browserify wraps the dependencies. Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## TL;DR;

In your case, it should be as simple as using;

```
$ = require('jquery/dist/jquery')(window);  // v2.1.0-beta2
```

It might be obvious; but you'll have to use this form of declaration (pass `window` to the result of `require`) in every module you use, not just one/ the first, etc.

---

## Non-TL;DR;

For anyone wanting to know *why*, the interesting code in jQuery which handles this is;

```
(function( window, factory ) {

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        // Expose a jQuery-making factory as module.exports in loaders that implement the Node
        // module pattern (including browserify).
        // This accentuates the need for a real window in the environment
        // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
        module.exports = function( w ) {
            w = w || window;
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
    } else {
        factory( window );
    }

// Pass this, window may not be defined yet
}(this, function( window ) {

    // All of jQuery gets defined here, and attached to the (locally named variable) "window".

}));
```

Note the comments at the top which explicitly address browserify; in situations where jQuery is in CommonJs-land, instead of returning `jQuery` as we know it, it returns a function which, when passed an object (which should be `window`), returns jQuery.

---

To confuse the matter further, this setup code has changed again in the latest commit, so that `module.exports` is [determined like so](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ed20e7c645064822f4070a0c60195e4bcdaba683/src/intro.js);

```
module.exports = global.document ?
    factory( global ) :
    function( w ) {
        if ( !w.document ) {
            throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
        }

        return factory( w );
```

... such that if `this` *is* the `window` object when jQuery is `require()`'d, it will return a jQuery instance, or if not it'll return the factory function as before; so when 2.1.0 *actually* gets released, you'll have to remove the `(window)` call again.

Comment: Great answer, and thank you.For those looking, note that even with jQuery >=2 you still have to use `Backbone.$ = $;` after `Backbone = require('backbone');`

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and after a bit of reading, here => https://gist.github.com/gabeno/8950573 is my solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
var $ = require('./node_modules/jquery');
```

//replace sources

```
var jsdom = require("./node_modules/jsdom");
var window = jsdom.jsdom().createWindow();
var $ = require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery')(window);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the latest version(6.x) of jsdom and the latest version of jquery(2.1.4), you can do this like:

```
var $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().defaultView);
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution above with CreateWindow() did not work for me.

However, the following allowed me to get the latest version of JQuery working in node:

```
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow);
```

Comment: parentWindow but not the CreatWindow() works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was also able to include it like Johnny Zhao did - but needed to include jsdom first.

I installed jquery and jsdom versjon:
jquery@2.2.0 node_modules\jquery
jsdom@7.2.2 node_modules\jsdom

Then ran:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().defaultView);

$("<h1>test passes</h1>").appendTo("body");
console.log($("body").html());
```